# Where does focus go in my Windows Forms form?

Tags: c#, winforms, tab-ordering

I set focus with the `Tab order` tool of [Visual Studio 2010](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio#Visual_Studio_2010) for my component in a form. I tried a couple of times. Now, when focus is in the last `Tab Index` and if I press `TAB` many times, it goes somewhere I don't know. It never come to the first `Tab Index`. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: It is probably located on a control that's covered by another control so you cannot see it either in the designer or in the tab-order window.  Use View + Other Windows + Document Outline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try two things here:

1. Try to remove some of your controls and see if the focus problem is fixed, if not, remove more and more until it will be fixed and then you will have a better clue of which control ruins the order.
2. Each control has a `Focused` property. you can have a different thread running over all of your controls and checks which one has this property value on "true".

   - this is a bit long but if you can't find the problem in a different way you can try that
   - more about the `Focused` property [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focused.aspx)